# Oracle EM 13c automatically logged in as dbsnmp

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I created a custom super administrator user in Oracle EM 13C.

When this super administrator is accessing a portable container (PDB) it is always logged in as dbsnmp. I cannot find any option to set custom own credentials.

[image: Lable shows user is logged in as dbsnmp to target PDB]

When I use the sysman account on EM 13C, I get asked for credentials to connect to database.

Why it does not ask the custom super administrator user for credentials? Only the sysman? Am I missing some privileges in the super administrator user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

Login with the custom super administrator account

Setup -> Security -> Preferred Credential

Select "Database Instance"

[image]
Click on "Manage Preferred Credentials" button above table.

Clear dbsnmp credentials under "Target Preferred Credentials".

Next time you access the database instance you will be asked to choose the credentials to use.